# glDrawArrays() draws one more unwanted object automatically

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to learn Modern OpenGL from [this site](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vertexarray.html#), I'm currently on Vertex arrays. I know we can minimise OpenGL function calls by using `glDrawArrays` instead of `glVertex**()` for each vertex.

From this point both those functions should result in the same output, but I'm getting additional drawing which I didn't make through `glDrawArrays()`.

Here is the code (Vertices and `display()` )

```
float Triangles[]={
0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 
-5.0f, -5.0f, -4.0f, 
5.0f, -5.0f, -4.0f,

0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 
-5.0f, -5.0f, 4.0f, 
5.0f, -5.0f, 4.0f,

0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 
-5.0f, -5.0f, -4.0f, 
-5.0f, -5.0f, 4.0f,

0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 
5.0f, -5.0f, -4.0f, 
5.0f, -5.0f, 4.0f,};
void display(void)
{
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0.1f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, Triangles);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Triangles));
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glFlush (); // Try commneting glFlush()
}
```

and when I run the program, it creates a 3D triangle as programmed, but with a 2D square shape with it (which I did NOT PROGRAM). What is it?? I dont know how OpenGL creates an object without the programmer's help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the 3rd argument of `glDrawArrays()`:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Triangles));
```

The value needs to be the number of **vertices**, while you are passing the size in **bytes**.

Since you have 12 vertices, the argument value should be 12. If you want to calculate it from the data definition, each vertex consists of 3 array element, so you have to divide the total size by 3 times the size of an array element:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(Triangles) / (3 * sizeof(Triangles[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `sizeof` is wrong. It will give you the array's size in bytes, not the number of vertices in the array.

To get the latter, write:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof Triangles / (3 * sizeof *Triangles));
```

[The documentation] says, regarding the final parameter (`count`):

> When `glDrawArrays` is called, it uses `count` sequential elements from each enabled array to construct a sequence of geometric primitives, beginning with element `first`.

It seems "element" means "triangle" in this case, which is what the `3` means; there are three `float`s in each vertex so we need to divide the number of `float`s by three to get the number of triangles to be drawn.

Also note that `sizeof` is not a function.

Comment: Thanks for high-lighting this statement, actually i was giving the return value of sizeof(Triangles) which is here 144, because each int occupies 4 bytes, and i have 36 vertices, so 4*36=144, ok now i found the bug i will answer my own question for a help for others, and but what do you mean by SizeOF() is not an function?? IT is a function because it contains () is'nt it?

Comment: @DeEp_FrEeze It is not a function, it's a unary operator. Notice that my code doesn't have any `()`s. Those are only needed when the argument is a type name, as in `sizeof (int)` since the argument then should look like a cast to the desired type. And I think you meant `float`, not `int` since `Triangles` in your code is an array of `float`.

Comment: oh yes, sorry its float, a float too occupies 4 bytes, and yes i too heard its an Operator, "the Sizeof() Operator" Not a function, but in c++ every keyword with a () is a function, so i thought its a function, ok leave that thats not the question, but thanks for highlighting it, the bug was that the glDrawArrays() take 144 bytes which was the return value of sizeof(Triangles); i only need to change it to sizeof(Triangles)/4; this makes my program works correctly...

Comment: @DeEp_FrEeze Don't change it to `sizeof(Triangles)/4`, please *read my code*. Change it to `sizeof Triangles / sizeof *Triangles`, that way you're not assuming that `float` is four bytes. Magic constants (like `4`) in code should be avoided, they are a source of bugs and confusion.

Comment: No 4 means the number of bytes a type occupies, in this case float which occupies 4 bytes and there are 36 arrays so sizeof(Triangles)/4 which is 144/4=36 and Yes your code too works, both the statement works and are the same, thanks for answering bro...

Comment: This answer looks wrong. The proposed expression calculates the number of floats in the array, while `glDrawArrays()` needs the number of vertices as the argument, where each vertex is defined by 3 floats.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes you were right, whatever the limit i give the opengl, it draws a new object if i crossed those limit(no. of vertices) at most it works as normal but at some time it generates the bug(creating a new object by doubling the vertex count as given to OpenGL), thus your Answer is correct, i got to this point when i tested your code when getting the same error again. Thanks Reto

Comment: @RetoKoradi Fine, I wasn't sure, fixed. Thanks.